# How to add custom items in 'Text long press context menu' in Android app?

Tags: android, custom-component, android-contextmenu

In latest versions of Android when we long touch over texts (in browser or text edit fields) some context menu appears as shown in image bellow.

[image]

My question is what are the names of these menus (highlighted in red blocks) ? And is there any way I can add my own customized item in the same menus ?

Comment: The top ones are action bars if you're targeting below API21.

Comment: The top red block is an action mode (a.k.a., contextual action bar). I'm not certain what the bottom one is implemented as. For your own app, you can attempt to add to the `EditText` default action mode [via `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback%28android.view.ActionMode.Callback%29). I am not aware of a way of modifying the bottom popup thing for your own app.

Comment: @CommonsWare, is it possible to modify Android's default Contextual Action Bar for all apps ? For example I want to make Similar item as 'Copy' and 'Select all' which will be available in all Android App's default Contextual Action Bar. Is there any way I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to modify Android's default Contextual Action Bar for all apps ?

No. Your Android SDK app cannot affect the UI of other apps in that fashion.

You are welcome to add your changes to a revised version of the Android framework in a custom ROM mod, though.